# Why JFrame redefine the "EXIT_ON_CLOSE" which it inherits from interface "WindowConstants"?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

`WindowConstants` is defined as this:

```
public interface WindowConstants
{
    public static final int DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE = 0;

    public static final int HIDE_ON_CLOSE = 1;

    public static final int DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE = 2;

    public static final int EXIT_ON_CLOSE = 3;

}
```

`JFrame` is defined as this:

```
public class JFrame  extends Frame implements WindowConstants,
                                              Accessible,
                                              RootPaneContainer,
                              TransferHandler.HasGetTransferHandler
{
    /**
     * The exit application default window close operation. If a window
     * has this set as the close operation and is closed in an applet,
     * a <code>SecurityException</code> may be thrown.
     * It is recommended you only use this in an application.
     * <p>
     * @since 1.3
     */
    public static final int EXIT_ON_CLOSE = 3;
```

Why the `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is redefined? And since it is `final` in the `WindowConstants` interface, how could it be redefined?

Comment: Why do you need the EXIT_ON_CLOSE  to be redefined?

Comment: No, I didn't redefine it. And I don't think need to. But it is defined in the JFrame as the source code shows. I just want to know why.

Comment: because in API is there HIDE_ON_CLOSE as default, it hasn't nothing with EXIT_ON_CLOSE :-)

Comment: changed in/from Java5/6 (latest 5 and new 6 versions)

Comment: @mKorbel I see there's a `private int defaultCloseOperation = HIDE_ON_CLOSE;` in `JFrame`. But I still don't get why there is a re-definition of `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` in `JFrame`.

Comment: to try output from JFrame.get/setDefaultCloseOperation....., there isn't reason, without casting to AWT.Frame, those nested/inherits whatever from AWT are implemented as methods in swing.JFrame

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java 1.3, when this was all added, `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` was relevant only to `JFrame` and not to other implementations of `WindowConstants`. As such - it was *not* present in `WindowConstants` and was defined in `JFrame`. The 3 other `XXX_ON_CLOSE` options were in the interface. (English Javadoc is not online anymore, though still downloadable, so no reference here. If you search for "WindowConstants Java 1.3" you'll get a Japanese version of the Javadoc - but since the page structure is the same, you can still see the point)

It was later (1.4) moved to `WindowConstants`, however the field was not removed from `JFrame` due to compatibility issues.

There is no redefining there. What's happening is [shadowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674474/in-java-if-a-child-class-shadows-a-static-parent-variable-with-an-instance-chil). I.e. the `JFrame` field hides (but does not eliminate) the `WindowConstants` field.

Comment: Thanks! And for others to reference, I paste the Japanese link of Java 1.3 `WindowConstants` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/1.3/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html