# WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE vs JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe

```
mainGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Intellij Code Analysis:

> Warning:(33, 46) Must be one of: WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,
>   WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE, WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE,
>   WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

SO,is it better to use  `WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` rather than  `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`?

Why?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358261/why-jframe-redefine-the-exit-on-close-which-it-inherits-from-interface-window) link out and see if it helps.

Comment: `JFrame` implements `WindowConstants`

Answer (score 1):

The two choices are the same.As you can see the method setDefaultCloseOperation() takes as a parameter an integer value so if you passed WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE or JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE it's the same.