# Variables binding VS method binding in polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I observer the behaviour that when we call a variable from a polymorphic object then it calls the parent's variable but when we call a method with the same polymorphic object then it calls child's method.Why this is the behaviour of polymorphism in Java? Why doesn't Java handle polymorphic variables and methods in same way?

```
class Parent{

    int age =10;

    public void showAge(){

        System.out.println("Parent Age:"+age);
    }
}

class ChildOne extends Parent{

    int age = 20;

    public void showAge(){

        System.out.println("child one age:"+age);
    }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent{

    int age = 30;

    public void showAge(){

        System.out.println("Child Two Age:"+age);
    }
}
public class Test{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parent parentChildOne = new ChildOne();
        System.out.println("parentChildOne.age: "+parentChildOne.age);
        parentChildOne.showAge();

        Parent parentChildTwo = new ChildTwo();
        System.out.println("parentChildTwo.age: "+parentChildTwo.age);
        parentChildTwo.showAge();

    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
parentChildOne.age: 10
child one age:20
parentChildTwo.age: 10
Child Two Age:30
```

Comment: Variables aren't polymorphic.

Comment: Good comparison. I tried it out myself. Let's say if superclass and subclass have one instance field named the same - var. Then casting the object will change the result. "((Superclass) subclassObj).var" gives the Superclass's instance field var. So I suppose variable names in Java are resolved by the reference type, not the actual obj type they are referencing.

Comment: while method names are dynamic binding, which uses the actual obj type. So it comes the polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all keep in mind that `Your variables are not polymorphic` and the next climax thing is your this point

```
  Parent parentChildOne = new ChildOne();
  Parent parentChildTwo = new ChildTwo();
```

See when you are trying to call a method using `Parent parentChildOne` then it should call the child's method because it is overrided and according to polymorphism it should be called. 
Now see again `Parent parentChildOne` same object for variables , now here is nothing with polymorphism but jvm is dealing it now with the concept of `shadowing`
So thats why they both are showing their real behaviours
Please follow this tutorial of [shadowing in java](http://blog.sanaulla.info/2008/06/27/shadowing-variables-in-java-demystified/)

Comment: good now i can understand the difference.Good example of their behaviour :) thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not polymorphic in Java.

Instead, instance variables in child classes *shadow*  instance variables with the same name in the parent class.
See also [Can parent and child class in Java have same instance variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501060/can-parent-and-child-class-in-java-have-same-instance-variable)

Answer (score 0):

`parentChildOne` and `parentChildTwo` are of type `Parent`. So you are printing `age` of the `Parent`. Same happes with the `showAge()` method but the value of `age` is shadowed by the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the comments into,

```
class Parent{

    int age =10;

    public void showAge(){

        System.out.println("Parent Age:"+age);
    }
}

class ChildOne extends Parent{
    //when you extends Parent the inherited members are like
    //and initialized into the default constructor
    // int super.age =10; 
    int age = 20;

    public void showAge(){

        System.out.println("child one age:"+age);
    }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent{
    //when you extends Parent the inherited members are like
    //and initialized into the default constructor
    // int super.age =10; 
    int age = 30;

    public void showAge(){

        System.out.println("Child Two Age:"+age);
    }
}
public class Test{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parent parentChildOne = new ChildOne();
            // when we call like this, goes to the parent type of the variable instead of object. 
        System.out.println("parentChildOne.age: "+parentChildOne.age);
        parentChildOne.showAge();

        Parent parentChildTwo = new ChildTwo();
            // when we call like this, goes to the parent type of the variable instead of object. 
        System.out.println("parentChildTwo.age: "+parentChildTwo.age);
        parentChildTwo.showAge();

    }
}
```